# Apache is leaking semaphores when running mod_mono

Tags: apache, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, mod-mono

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC2 application under mod_mono with mono 2.8.1 and currently have to periodically clear out semaphore arrays that apache seems to be leaking.

I started with mono rpm's for 2.6.7 a while back but had had some issues both with leaking semaphore arrays (i.e. more and more accumulating in **ipcs**) and some incompatibility with ASP.NET MVC2, so I built 2.8 from source. The leak continued, so I just built 2.8.1 from source and the same thing is still happening. This is on an Amazon AMI (i guess it's centos under the hood). The symptoms are that semaphore arrays keep building up and if i don't manually remove them with **ipcrm** after a while requests to ASP.NET pages return no content with no errors in the logs. I've also reproduced the same issue in an centos 5.4 AMI.

Is anyone successfully running ASP.NET under apache/mod_mono and I'm just running into some edge case? Since I can't find any mentions of this happening  to anyone else, I assume it's not general ASP.NET bug. Any ideas how i can troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Just a comment, i am using mod_mono on my production server (but, its not much. I host 4 sites no one ever visits) and i havent notice any problems or leaks. The keyword is notice. However want to mention i did have problems with 2.8 so i reverted to Mono 2.6.7. So maybe you should consider switching back if 2.8 doesnt solve that problem. I am using the lastest 2.6.* of mono, XSP, Mod_Mono and GDIplus. Originally i downgraded just mono but it didnt seem to like the mix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally figured this out and while the solution exposes my own mistake of not following up other warning I was receiving, i figure this should be useful to anyone else runnning into this.

By default apache config has the below config order:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
```

I.e. all conf files (usually where vhosts are defined) are loaded before httpd user and group are set. This results in the below warning on restart:

```
[Mon Jan 24 00:12:50 2011] [crit] The unix daemon module not initialized yet.
Please make sure that your mod_mono module is loaded after the User/Group
directives have been parsed. Not initializing the dashboard.
```

While everything seems to work anyhow, this is the cause for the semaphore leak. If you move the `Include` after the `User/Group`, the warning goes away and mod_mono no longer leaks semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this with the shared memory used by cross-process handles.

My fix was to set MONO_DISABLE_SHM=1, however I'm not sure if this is your problem since the cross-process handle support is disabled starting with 2.8.

You could probably still try MONO_DISABLE_SHM to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Tried setting it via MonoSetEnv but I've already built up about 20 semaphore arrays and none have been removed :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new [sgen](http://www.mono-project.com/Compacting_GC) garbage collector instead of Boehm.

> To use the new garbage collector, you
>   just need to invoke Mono with the
>   --gc=sgen command line option, or set the MONO_ENV_OPTIONS environment
>   variable to contain "--gc=sgen"
>   option. By default Mono continues to
>   use the Boehm collector.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but it is my impression that the semaphores are an IPC mechanism to coordinate XSP and apache, so unrelated to .NET garbage collection

Comment: After testing, this hasn't changed anything. Still leaking semaphore arrays :(